# How to transpose a 4D tensor in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, linear-algebra, tensor, ncnn

I need to pre-process the input of an ML model into the correct shape.
In order to do that, I need to transpose a tensor from `ncnn` in C++.
The API does not offer a `transpose`, so I am trying to implement my own transpose function.

The input tensor has the shape `(1, 640, 640, 3)` (for `batch`, `x`, `y` and `color`) and I need to reshape it to the shape `(1, 3, 640, 640)`.

How do I properly and efficiently transpose the tensor?

```cpp
ncnn:Mat& preprocess(const cv::Mat& rgba) {
    int width = rgba.cols;
    int height = rgba.rows;

    // Build a tensor from the image input
    ncnn::Mat in = ncnn::Mat::from_pixels(rgba.data, ncnn::Mat::PIXEL_RGBA2RGB, width, height);

    // Set the current shape of the tesnor 
    in = in.reshape(1, 640, 640, 3);

    // Normalize
    const float norm_vals[3] = {1 / 255.f, 1 / 255.f, 1 / 255.f};
    in.substract_mean_normalize(0, norm_vals);

    // Prepare the transposed matrix
    ncnn::Mat transposed = new ncnn::Mat(in.w, in.c, in.h, in.d, sizeof(float));
    ncnn::Mat shape = transposed->shape();

    // Transpose
    
    for (int i = 0; i < in.w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < in.h; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < in.d; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l > in.c; l++) {
                    int fromIndex = ???;
                    int toIndex = ???;
                    transposed[toIndex] = in[fromIndex];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return transposed; 
}
```

Comment: In your code, you `new` an object which you then return a reference to? That makes no sense! Either return the pointer (preferably inside a `std::shared`), or create the object on the stack and return it by value.

Comment: Are you sure you `reshape` correctly? Width and height are first two parameters of the function, not second and third. Also, matrix elements are not all stored consecutively due to alignment considerations, only within a chanel they are consecutive. So to iterate over elements you should use `channel` function and use returned pointer to access elements, as in an example [here](https://github.com/Tencent/ncnn/blob/master/docs/Home.md#print-mat-content).

Comment: @CrisLuengo My CPP skills are rusty and I haven't run this code yet, might very well have some typos. Will update.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk this is the shape my model requires. I have python code that uses the same model correctly. You can see the python code over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467497/transposing-an-image-tensor-in-ncnn-for-yolov5

Comment: @Lizozom Layout of the matrix is not the same in OpenCV and ncnn. In ncnn matrix is c*d*h*w, and each d*h*w portion is continuous itself, but each is aligned to 16 bytes for performance purposes, so to easily access matrix elements you can use the technique from aforementioned example. But note that order of `reshape` arguments is w, h, d, c, so `in` is stored as 3*640*640*1 and implied mapping between your and ncnn dimensions is color=c,y=d,x=h,batch=w. Is it what you intended? If yes, transposed matrix will be stored as 640*640*3*1. Anyway, transpose is easy now when we can access elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only talking about index calculations, not the ncnn API which I'm not familiar with.

You set

```
fromIndex = i*A + j*B + k*C + l*D;
  toIndex = i*E + j*F + k*G + l*H;
```

where you compute `A B C D E F G H` based on the source and target layout. How?

Let's look at a simple 2D transposition first. Transpose a hw layout matrix to a wh layout matrix (slowest changing dimension first):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
          int fromIndex = i * w + j * 1;
          //              ^       ^
          //              |       |
          //             i<h     j<w        <---- hw layout

          int   toIndex = j * h + i * 1;
          //              ^       ^
          //              |       |
          //             j<w     i<h        <---- wh layout
      }      
  }
```

So when computing `fromIndex`, you start with the source layout (hw), you remove the first letter (h) and what remains (w) is your coefficient that goes with i, and you remove the next letter (w) and what remains (1) is your coefficient that goes with j. It is not hard to see that the same kind of pattern works in any number of dimensions. For example, if your source layout is dchw, then you have

```
fromIndex = i * (c*h*w) + j * (h*w) + k * (w) + l * (1);
//          ^             ^           ^         ^
//          |             |           |         |
//         i<d           j<c         k<h       l<w   <---- dchw
```

What about `toIndex`? Same thing but rearrange the letters from the slowest-changing to the fastest-changing *in the target layout*. For example, if your target layout is hwcd, then the order will be `k l j i` (because i is the index that ranges over [0..d), in both source and target layouts, etc). So

```
  toIndex = k * (w*c*d) + l * (c*d) + j * (d) + i * (1);
  //        ^             ^           ^         ^
  //        |             |           |         |
  //       k<h           l<w         j<c       i<d   <---- hwcd
```

I did not use your layouts on purpose. Do your own calculations a couple of times. You want to develop some intuition about this thing.

Comment: Not sure now well this answers the question, if at all, please let me know.

Comment: It actually does. I ended up needing to use a channel API, but from a quick look this looks similar to what I ended up doing. I'll review it a bit later! Thank you :)